# App starts, only a white screen, odd stream error message

Tags: flutter

I'm trying to run the app created by `flutter create first_try` (and I've made no changes to the code).

I'm on a mac running high sierra, Xcode 9.4.

If I run `flutter run`, it runs okay, and comes up in the iOS simulator just fine.

If I run it under IntelliJ, using the "run" button (green triangle), it runs fine, but I can't do hot-reloading, etc.

If I run it under IntelliJ, using the "debug" button (green bug), it opens in the simulator, but only shows a white screen.

I get the following message in the IntelliJ window:

```
Launching lib/main.dart on iPhone X in debug mode...
log: Must be admin to run 'stream' command
Script started, output file is /dev/null

Script done, output file is /dev/null
Starting Xcode build...
Xcode build done.
```

I've tried running `flutter clean`, and it doesn't help.

Here's the output of `flutter doctor -v`:

```
$ flutter doctor -v
[✓] Flutter (Channel beta, v0.4.4, on Mac OS X 10.13.5 17F77, locale en-US)
    • Flutter version 0.4.4 at /Volumes/Second/Chris/hacks/flutter/flutter
    • Framework revision f9bb4289e9 (4 weeks ago), 2018-05-11 21:44:54 -0700
    • Engine revision 06afdfe54e
    • Dart version 2.0.0-dev.54.0.flutter-46ab040e58

[!] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK 28.0.0)
    • Android SDK at /Users/chris/Library/Android/sdk
    • Android NDK location not configured (optional; useful for native profiling support)
    • Platform android-28, build-tools 28.0.0
    • Java binary at: /Users/chris/hacks/flutter/jdk-10.0.1.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 10.0.1+10)
    ✗ Android license status unknown.

[✓] iOS toolchain - develop for iOS devices (Xcode 9.4)
    • Xcode at /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
    • Xcode 9.4, Build version 9F1027a
    • ios-deploy 1.9.2
    • CocoaPods version 1.5.3

[✗] Android Studio (not installed)
    • Android Studio not found; download from https://developer.android.com/studio/index.html
      (or visit https://flutter.io/setup/#android-setup for detailed instructions).

[✓] IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition (version 2018.1.4)
    • IntelliJ at /Users/chris/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA CE.app
    • Flutter plugin version 25.0.2
    • Dart plugin version 181.4892.1

[!] VS Code (version 1.24.0)
    • VS Code at /Users/chris/Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents
    • Dart Code extension not installed; install from
      https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Dart-Code.dart-code

[✓] Connected devices (1 available)
    • iPhone X • D34D5096-B3F9-4930-822B-48D3BD71B83D • ios • iOS 11.4 (simulator)

! Doctor found issues in 3 categories.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It could be a couple of things some stuff you might find helpful:

1.) Try restarting your computer

2.) Some references:

https://github.com/flutter/flutter-intellij

https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter

https://flutter.io/using-ide/

3.)Check your log output flutter doctor -v

4.) Make sure everything is up to date

5.) Check your flutter channel using the flutter channel command
maybe try flutter channel master

6.) Try flutter upgrade

7.) Maybe even try installing everything else flutter doctor says is missing.

I am currently trying to learn Flutter using Android devices not iOS

Comment: 1). You must be a windows user :-)  Tried it anyway, didn't help.  Thanks for the other references.  3) doesn't make a whole lot of sense... I have the `flutter docter -v` output above.  I might try the "install everything", I will want to do android at some point.

Comment: I am a windows user correct :). My apologies I meant the log output of flutter logs. Install everything hopefully works! Sorry, I'm not of more help.

Comment: No problem -- thanks for responding!  Your suggestion to look at the flutter-intellij plugin was spot on.  I posted an issue there, and they determined it's actually in flutter itself (!) so they moved the issue over there.  We'll see...

Comment: Sorry for responding on this Late but I'm glad it's been taken over there and the plugin helped :) Happy programming

Answer (score 1):

This issue happens when the logged in user does not have root permissions.
This started after an OSX update.

Follow this Flutter issue https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/18409

Answer (score 1):

Switeched from flutter master to flutter stable but no success. Then switched back to master channel and it started working.